# Could two tf.data.Dataset coexist and controled by tf.cond()

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I put two `Dataset` pipeline for train/test = 9:1 set in my Graph and the control the flow by a tf.cond. I encountered a problem that during the training the both pipelines are activated at each step. The testset ran out before the trainset as it has less during training.

> OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence

First, nest the input pipeline in a function:

```
def input_pipeline(*args):
    ...
    # construct iterator
    it = batch.make_initializable_iterator()
    iter_init_op = it.initializer

    # get next img and label
    X_it, y_it = it.get_next()
    inputs = {'img': X_it, 'label': y_it, 'iterator_init_op': iter_init_op}
    return inputs
```

Then initiate:

```
train_input = input_pipeline(args)
test_input = input_pipeline(args)
```

In the model, we put a placeholder to fill condition with feed_dict which won't penalize the performance:

```
...
def f1(): return train_input
def f2(): return test_input
cond_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='cond_pl')
input = tf.cond(tf.equal(cond_pl, 'train'), lambda: f1(), lambda: f2())
...
```

Within the session:

```
for ep in range(nb_ep):
   ...
   for step in range(ep_len):
       print('step:{}\r'.format(step))
       try:
           sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={cond_pl: 'train'})
           if step % step_len == (step_len - 1):
               sess.run([test_op], feed_dict={cond_pl: 'test'})
       except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
           raise('drop the remainder')
   ...
```

How can I let the input pipeline `get_next()` get called only if the condition fits?

---

**Snippet to play around updated based on @sharky answer:**

```
def write_h5(args):
    x, is_training = args
    with h5py.File('./{}_{}.h5'.format('train' if is_training else 'test', x), 'w') as f:
        h = w = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.02)
        hh, _ = np.meshgrid(h, w)
        a = hh ** 2
        b = np.add(a + 1, np.random.randn(100, 100))  #do something and add gaussian noise
        f.create_dataset('X', shape=(100, 100), dtype='float32', data=a)
        f.create_dataset('y', shape=(100, 100), dtype='float32', data=b)


def input_pipeline(window_size, batch_size, is_train=True, ncores=mp.cpu_count()):
    flist = []
    for dirpath, _, fnames in os.walk('./'):
        for fname in fnames:
            if fname.startswith('train' if is_train else 'test') and fname.endswith('.h5'):
                print(fname)
                flist.append((os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)), str(window_size)))
    f_len = len(flist)
    print(f_len)
    # init list of files
    batch = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(flist)))
    batch = batch.map(_pyfn_wrapper, num_parallel_calls=ncores)
    batch = batch.shuffle(batch_size).batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(ncores).repeat()

    # construct iterator
    it = batch.make_initializable_iterator()
    iter_init_op = it.initializer

    # get next img and label
    X_it, y_it = it.get_next()
    inputs = {'img': X_it, 'label': y_it, 'iterator_init_op': iter_init_op}
    return inputs, f_len


def _pyfn_wrapper(args):
    return tf.py_func(parse_h5,  #wrapped pythonic function
                      [args],
                      [tf.float32, tf.float32]  #[input, output] dtype
                      )

def parse_h5(args):
    name, window_size = args
    window_size = int(window_size.decode('utf-8'))
    with h5py.File(name, 'r') as f:
        X = f['X'][:].reshape(window_size, window_size, 1)
        y = f['y'][:].reshape(window_size, window_size, 1)
        return X, y


# init data
p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
p.map(write_h5, zip(range(9000), repeat(True)))
p.map(write_h5, zip(range(1000), repeat(False)))

# hparam
ep_len = 90
step_len = 9  # run test_op after 9 steps

# create tf.data.Dataset
train_input, train_len = input_pipeline(100, 5, is_train=True)
test_input, test_len = input_pipeline(100, 5, is_train=False)


# draw graph
def f1(): return train_input
def f2(): return test_input


cond_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=None, name='cond_pl')
input = tf.cond(tf.equal(cond_pl, 'train'), lambda: f1(), lambda: f2())  # I thou

with tf.name_scope("Conv1"):
    W = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[3, 3, 1, 1],
                         initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    b = tf.get_variable("b", shape=[1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    layer1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input['img'], W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + b
    logits = tf.nn.relu(layer1)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=input['label'], predictions=logits))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(loss)
test_op = print(loss)
#

# session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for ep in range(5):
        print('ep:{}'.format(ep))
        sess.run(input['iterator_init_op'], feed_dict={cond_pl: 'train'})
        sess.run(input['iterator_init_op'], feed_dict={cond_pl: 'test'})
        for step in range(ep_len):
            print('step:{}\r'.format(step))
            try:
                sess.run([train_op], feed_dict={cond_pl: 'train'})
                if step % step_len == (step_len - 1):
                    sess.run([test_op], feed_dict={cond_pl: 'test'})
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                raise('drop the remainder')
```

Comment: Why don't create two separate dataset objects and two iterators?

Comment: @Sharky I did and they are controled by tf.cond. Can you please detail a little bit?

Comment: First of all, you can use `repeat()` to handle out of range error. Second, maybe i miss smth,  why even bother with cond? I'll post an answer with example, and you let me know if it suits your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider example:

```py
train = np.arange(90)
test = np.arange(10)

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train).shuffle(10).batch(10).repeat()
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test).shuffle(10).batch(10).repeat()

train_iterator = train_ds.make_initializable_iterator()
test_iterator = test_ds.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
    sess.run(test_iterator.initializer)
    for i in range(len(train) + 1):
        print(sess.run(train_iterator.get_next()))
        if i % 9 == 8:
            print(sess.run(test_iterator.get_next()))
```

Two datasets, two iterators, both initialized at startup. When `i` exceeds length of datasets, it starts repeating both of them because of `repeat()`. If it'll be called with num_epochs or not called at all, you'll get end of sequence. If for some reason you need/want to use `cond`, maybe this answer will help

[How to use Tensorflow's tf.cond() with two different Dataset iterators without iterating both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622490/how-to-use-tensorflows-tf-cond-with-two-different-dataset-iterators-without-i)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. initializers were reinitialized ever iteration. Fixed