# Trying to resolve training/testing summaries using tf.Data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm looking to develop summaries during my NN training, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146428/show-training-and-validation-accuracy-in-tensorflow-using-same-graph), but all the examples I see are using feed_dict and not tf.data. My training and testing have separate initializers:

```
self.train_init = iterator.make_initializer(train_data) # initializer for train_data
self.test_init = iterator.make_initializer(test_data)   # initializer for test_data
```

During my training, I initialize the training initializer with sess.run(self.train_init), but in order to test the accuracy I need to to initialize sess.run(self.test_init) I believe. Currently my code is shown below:

```
for i in range(100):
    sess.run(self.train_init)
    total_loss = 0
    n_batches = 0
    try:
        while True:
              _, l = sess.run([self.optimizer, self.loss])
              total_loss += l
              n_batches += 1
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        pass

        if i % (10/1) == 0:
           print('Avg. loss epoch {0}: {1}'.format(i, total_loss/n_batches))
           acc, summ = sess.run(self.accuracy, self.summary_op)
           writer.add_summary(summ, i)
```

As it currently stands, accuracy is measured every 10 iterations, but its using the training batch, not the testing batch. I want to be able to see the training and testing accuracy over time in order to see clearly whether or not over-fitting is occurring (good training accuracy but poor testing accuracy).

I have no idea how to do this when I'm using tf.Data. How do I switch between initializers while going through 100 iterations, all the while creating summaries of what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually one evaluates the test set outside the training process in order to optimize the performance. But if you really want to do it *in-situ*, one of the solution which works perfectly for me is to:

1. Create two tf.data, and a placeholder to switch between these.
2. Use a tf.cond() to control the flow like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516484/could-two-tf-data-dataset-coexist-and-controled-by-tf-cond)

The code might look something like:

```
with tf.name_scope('train_pipeline'):
    train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(...)
    ...
    train_ds = iterator.make_initializer(train_data)
    train_init = iterator.initialize
    X_iterator_train = iterator.get_next()
with tf.name_scope('test_pipeline'):
    test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(...)
    ...
    test_ds = iterator.make_initializer(test_data)
    test_init = iterator.initialize
    X_iterator_test = iterator.get_next()

train_or_test = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='switch_buton')
def f1(): X_iterator_train
def f2(): X_iterator_test
inputs = tf.cond(tf.equal(train_or_test, 'train'), lambda :f1(), lambda: f2(), name='input_cond')

# model
... # use your input(IteratorGetNext) at your first layer, something like tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, ...)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # init summary writers for two different path
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(...)
    test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(...)

    for ep in range(nb_epoch):
        sess.run([train_init, test_init])
        # begin training
        for step in range(nb_batch):
            # 90% train, 10% test
            if step % 9 == 0:
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={train_or_test: 'test'})  # switch to test input pipeline
                train_writer.add_summary()
            else:
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={train_or_test: 'train'})  # switch to train input pipeline
                test_writer.add_summary()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I may ask a follow up, I already have it set where testing accuracy is tested after training as a batch (as is convention). But there is no way to see training and testing accuracy concurrently, over each epoch, to see overfitting. The tensorflow website uses a similiar approach to you using the feed_dict approach (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard), but neither you or the example uses tf.Data structures. So, is there no way to do it, or, conventionally is it never done because of penalties to performance?

Comment: @JamieDimon it's indicated in the comment. This approach uses `tf.data.Dataset`

Comment: Now there's more details

Comment: I see it now, thanks, and that certainly answers my question.